# Moving marker to user location in Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I was trying to make a map activity app which when run, displays user's GPS' location on a map using a marker. However, on running, it just displays the marker in the  default location (Sydney) please help. Below is my code.. I have tried a number of ways but all of them still lead me to Sydney. What Im trying to do is for the app to take me directly to my location once run.
Below is my code;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_real_time_location);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}



public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            try {
                latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Current Position"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
            catch (SecurityException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATES_DISTANCE, locationListener);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LocationCallback instead to get your latest location:

```
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
        if (locationList.size() > 0) {
            //The last location in the list is the newest
            Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
            Log.i(TAG, "Location " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            //Create instance for current user lat and lng
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            // Add user position marker
            currentUserPositionMarker(latLng);

            //move map camera
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, CURRENT_MAP_ZOOM));

        }
    }
};

/**
 * Add Marker for user current position
 *
 * @param latLng current lat and lng of user
 */
private void currentUserPositionMarker(LatLng latLng) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(CURRENT_POSITION);
    mCurrLocationMarker = gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

     //move map camera
     gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, CURRENT_MAP_ZOOM));
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mFusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    gMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(SET_INTERVAL_FOR_ACTIVE_LOCATION_UPDATES); // 3 seconds interval
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(SET_INTERVAL_FOR_ACTIVE_LOCATION_UPDATES);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (isFineLocationPermissionGranted())
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the last known location of the device, use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java) link to get the last known location, and then display the marker where you want.